# Firebase Project with two apps

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I´m trying to connect two Apps to same database project with firebase, I can create a new user into new application to the same database but when I try to retrieve data valueeventlistener always return null after few seconds, I check already google-services.json and two files are different, packages and ids, is there someone with same problem?

```
        Query query = myRef.child("xxxx/").orderByChild("xxxx").equalTo(Utils.decodeEmail(userEmail));
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String stLogoUrl;
            stLogoUrl = dataSnapshot.child("imageEncode").getValue(String.class);
            try {
                if (stLogoUrl!=null) {
                    bitmapPhotoProfile[0] = decodeFromFirebaseBase64(stLogoUrl);
                } else {

                }
                imgLogo.setImageBitmap(bitmapPhotoProfile[0]);
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

[image: result query with debug]

Comment: Post your code buddy... No one can help u otherwise

Comment: Can you log the message inside onCancelled() firebase method ?

Comment: Kushan, Rahul Chandrabhan, I add the code!